# git add except 1 folder

Tags: git

I don't want to submit projectname.project folder. Now, I use like that

```
git add .
...

...
git push orign master
```

I don't want to submit projectname.project folder. When i use

```
git rm -r projectname.project
```

git remove my projectname.project in my computer and I need to create a project again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete from index in git not in your filesystem

`git rm -r projectname.project --cached`

Now this directory is delete in versonning not in your filesystem

Answer (score 7):

add it to .gitignore (more about on [github guide](http://github.com/guides/ignore-for-git))

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you want to do:

1. If you only want to not add projectname.project to index and actual commit, but leave for future git monitoring, then `git reset projectname.project` should work
2. If you want to completly remove porjectname.project from tracking by git then add this to .gitignore (to prevent adding this in the future), remove it from cache (if it has been already tracked) with `git rm --cached projectname.project`